# erro conversão de array para int em linguagem c

Tags: array, conversão

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender qual o erro estou cometendo nesta conversão. pois qdo digito para imprimir os últimos caracteres da variável **chave_temp**, **chave_temp2** ou **chave**, ele esta imprimindo '\0'.

// copia os dados do argv1 para a variável chave
    strcpy(chave_temp2, argv[1]);                    // copia a string argv[1] para a char chave_temp

```
for(int i = 0; i < compr_argv1; i++)            // tive que copiar a chave_temp2 para a chave_temp, porque estava gerando falha
{
    chave_temp[i] = chave_temp2[i];
    chave[i] = chave_temp[i];
}
```

Comment: Porque você não utiliza strcpy para copiar também para chave_temp e chave?

Comment: eu havia utilizado a strcpy para a chave_temp, mas ocorreu erro na conversão, também. então fiz um strcpy na chave_temp2 para copia-la via "for". Com a variável "chave" não sei se é possível usar a strcpy, porque ela é uma int.